# pycharm does not connect with console with python3.8

Tags: python, terminal, console, pycharm, python-3.8

```
"G:\Everything python\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/dell/PycharmProjects/untitled8/python test.py"
No Python at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe'
Process finished with exit code 103
```

Everytime I try to make any sort of code in pycharm.Even something basic like print(1).I get hit with this code.I tried uninstalling and reinstalling python and pycharm but it didn't work.[Please Help]

Comment: select the right interpreter

Answer (score 0):

In PyCharm, check `File - Settings ... - Project - Project Interpretor`. It's probably pointing to a location where you no longer have Python installed.

The reason this doesn't go away after a reinstall is because you probably didn't tell PyCharm to remove all previous settings. The reason this happens at all is because PyCharm supports (like any good Python IDE) multiple installations of Python and virtual environments.